# Make \translate'd string uppercase

Tags: formatting, languages

I'd like to typeset German weekday names in uppercase using the translator package but I can't get it working:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{translator}
\usedictionary{translator-months-dictionary}

\begin{document}

\translate{Monday}
\uppercase{\translate{Monday}}
\expandafter\uppercase\expandafter{\translate{Monday}}
\MakeUppercase{\translate{Monday}}
\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{\translate{Monday}}

\end{document}
```

The result is

```
Montag MONDAY MONDAY MONDAY MONDAY
```

How to get `MONTAG`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
   \translatelet\foo{Monday}\MakeUppercase{\foo}
```

or for the pgf example

```
{\def\translate#1{\translatelet\foo{#1}\MakeUppercase{\foo}}%
\pgfcalendarweekdayname{0}}
```

Comment: Even though egreg's explanation is better you got the answer for my problem, I wrapped your code in a `\newcommand{\weekdaynameUC}[1]{...#1->##1...}` which perfectly fits my needs. Thanks @David, and thanks @egreg as well for the good explanation.

Comment: @cgnieder thanks for the reminder, now I did so

Answer (score 7):

With `\uppercase{\translate{Monday}}` you're simply doing

```
\translate{MONDAY}
```

which results in "MONDAY" because the string isn't know. The same happens with the other tries, because `\translate` doesn't expand in a unique step (and is not fully expandable either).

Here's a way out: the command `\translate{xyz}` actually calls

```
\translatelet\trans@temp{xyz}\trans@temp
```

that is it stores the translated string into `\trans@temp` and then uses the string. So we can use the same mechanism and put `\MakeUppercase` in the proper place. I'll define `\translateUC` with the same syntax as `\translate`:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{translator}
\usedictionary{translator-months-dictionary}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\translateUC}[2][]{%
  \translatelet[#1]\trans@temp{#2}%
  \MakeUppercase{\trans@temp}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\translate{Monday}

\translateUC{Monday}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps my MWE was a little bit to simple, actually I'd like to make `\pgfcalendarweekdayname{0}` uppercase. However from the answers I can't figure out how to do this, I thought it just has something to do with the correct order of expansion.